# AngularJS + Datatables + Dropdownlist

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I'm using AngularJS to populate my datatable. What I want to know is how can I populate the datatable based on the dropdownlist

This is my dropdownlist

```
<div>
     Get Users with Role:
     <select id="ddlRole" data-ng-model="selectedRole" data-ng-change="populateDataTable()" data-ng-options="v.name for (k,v) in roles"></select>
     <input type="hidden" value="{{selectedRole}}" />
 </div>
```

This is my angular code

```
$scope.roles = [
    {name: 'XXX' },
    {name: 'YYY' }
];
$scope.selectedRole = $scope.roles[0];

//onchange event
 $scope.populateDataTable = function () {
    $scope.selectedRole = $scope.selectedRole.name;
    RefreshDataTable(); //TODO
};
```

How can I change this to make an ajax call to retreive the data, populate the datatable based on the dropdownlist value and **retain the value of dropdownlist** as well.

I'm sure we can do this using JQuery but I dont want to mix these and make a mess. Is there any way I can acheive this using **AngularJS**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple data table directive:

```
    appModule.directive('dataTable', [function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

        // apply DataTable options, use defaults if none specified by user
        var options = {};
        if (attrs.myTable.length > 0) {
            options = scope.$eval(attrs.myTable);
        } else {
            options = {
                "bStateSave": true,
                "iCookieDuration": 2419200, /* 1 month */
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bDestroy": true
            };
        }

        // Tell the dataTables plugin what columns to use
        // We can either derive them from the dom, or use setup from the controller           
        var explicitColumns = [];
        element.find('th').each(function (index, elem) {
            explicitColumns.push($(elem).text());
        });
        if (explicitColumns.length > 0) {
            options["aoColumns"] = explicitColumns;
        } else if (attrs.aoColumns) {
            options["aoColumns"] = scope.$eval(attrs.aoColumns);
        }

        // aoColumnDefs is dataTables way of providing fine control over column config
        if (attrs.aoColumnDefs) {
            options["aoColumnDefs"] = scope.$eval(attrs.aoColumnDefs);
        }

        if (attrs.fnRowCallback) {
            options["fnRowCallback"] = scope.$eval(attrs.fnRowCallback);
        }

        // apply the plugin
        var dataTable = element.dataTable(options);



        // watch for any changes to our data, rebuild the DataTable
        scope.$watch(attrs.aaData, function (value) {
            var val = value || null;
            if (val) {
                dataTable.fnClearTable();
                dataTable.fnAddData(scope.$eval(attrs.aaData));
            }
        });

        if (attrs.useParentScope) {
            scope.$parent.dataTable = dataTable;
        } else {
            scope.dataTable = dataTable;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then initialize it in your controller. Override fnServerData method, append your selected value (selected role) and filter data on server side.

```
    $scope.overrideOptions = {
            "bStateSave": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 8,
            "bProcessing": false,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": 'Data/Get',
            "bFilter": false,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "sServerMethod": 'POST',        ,
            "fnServerData": function(sUrl, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
                var data = {
                    dataTableRequest: aoData,
                    selectedDropDownValue: $scope.selectedRole
                };

                $http.post(sUrl, data).success(function (json) {
                    if (json.sError) {
                        oSettings.oApi._fnLog(oSettings, 0, json.sError);
                    }

                    $(oSettings.oInstance).trigger('xhr', [oSettings, json]);
                    fnCallback(json);
                });
            }
     };

var columnDefs = [
                        {
                            "mData": "id",                            
                            "bSortable": false,
                            "bSearchable": false,                            
                            "aTargets": ['tb-id']
                        },
                        {
                            "mData": "data",
                            "aTargets": ['tb-data']                            
                        }
];
```

Refresh the datatable on select change.

```
$scope.populateDataTable = function () {         
     if ($scope.dataTable) {
         $scope.dataTable.fnDraw();
     }  
  };
```

Html markup:

```
<table  class="display m-t10px" data-table="overrideOptions" ao-column-defs="columnDefs">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th class="tb-id"></th>           
              <th class="tb-data></th>               
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: May I know which part of it triggers an onchangeevent on dropdownlist? Thank You.

Comment: @Sup A added a missing part.

Comment: Is `dataTable` the id of the table? Because it isn't refreshing the table. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Sup the $scope.dataTable is a variable which contains a reference to the dataTable plugin's instance. The variable is initialized inside the directive.

Comment: I was missing dataTable plugin's instance then. Thank You.

Comment: How do I retain the value of dropdownlist here? Its being set to the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Hope above your code is in controller.
Inject $http and make a $http get or post call

```
$scope.populateDataTable = function () {
     $scope.selectedRole = $scope.selectedRole.name;
      $http.get('api/controller', function(result){
        //response from the service call in result
       });
  };
```